# K means and hierarchical

Tags: dataset

I have some insurance data - 5,00,000 records with around 50 variables :categorical,continuous and binary variables.Some of my categorical variables have 30+ categories.I am trying to build clusters using hierarchical and K means both. My system has good configuration and it works with such huge data on both the clustering algorithms in R.

I have normalized the quantitative variables, converted binary categories to (0,1). But how should I treat such categorical variables with 30 different categories. If I create 29 dummy variables and do the same exercise for all the categorical variables, my dataset might have 200 variables. I am not sure if this is the right way to go ahead.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Are those 30 categories on an ordinal or on a nominal scale? If nominal, I suppose you'll need those dummies. I am not that familiar with clustering in R but I would suppose it will be similar to regression in R: that is you don't have to build dummy variables yourself. Instead just check, that your data type is factor and most likely R will deal with it automatically.

Comment: Thanks.I have different types of variables. Few are ordinal (like policy_issuance year) and few are nominal (like occupation). Yes, I can use "Factor" in R to convert the nominal variables into dummies and that shouldn't be a challenge. How should I treat ordinal variables like policy_issuance_year? Further, is it Ok to have 200+ variables to implement clustering algorithm or shall I use something like PCA to reduce dimensionality and then implement clustering?